# Pythons request libary: HttpBasicAuth and german umlaute (äüöß)

Tags: python, request, http-auth

I ran into a problem using the HttpBasicAuth with my password that contained *ß*. On a Windows mashine. Now I will not be able to chage my companies password rules so I want to display some kind of warning when a password is not supported. Or is there a solution to HttpBasicAuth struggeling with german umlaute?

Answer (score 1):

So I found an solution. What I was using was `password = getpass.getpass()` to read in the password. Adding `.encode("utf-8")` fixed my problem.

So read in the password as:

```
password = getpass.getpass().encode("utf-8")
```